# Who feel more impact of fall

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, drag

A person jumping from a higher building is likely to suffer less injury than the person jumping from a short building as the person from large building fall long enough to attain drag force which means the acceleration = 0 m/s square and body falls with constant speed?

I got this doubt after reading drag force portion in Halliday Resnick Walker's "Principles of Physics". Please give the answer with appropriate explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Is it the final speed or final acceleration that determines a person's injuries when he/she hits the floor ?

A skydiver can reach terminal velocities of between 60-90 m/s. At terminal velocity, a = 0.

If you jump off a chair, you'll probably reach velocities of less than 1m/s. However, your acceleration will be $9.8m/s^2$.

In other words, it is not the final acceleration that determine the impulse force. It is the final velocity (along with the hardness of the floor).

Comment: More specifically, it depends upon your kinetic energy just before you hit the ground.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the forces are proportional to the impact momentum. Before impact you have $J=m v$ momentum and it needs to be 0 after the impact (unless you bounce!). Newtons laws tells us that $J=\int F(t)\,{\rm d}t$ so the force needed depends on the total momentum $J$ and the time it takes for the impact event to happen.